# histogram bucket aggregation with custom metric

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Index has documents like:

`{'_size': 200, 'field': [1,2,3,4]}`

I need to retrieve dependency `_size( field.length )`
Or *average* and *variation* of `_size` for each `field.length`

Is this possible to achieve that with a single query?

I found there is a [histogram bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) but it only returns the *doc_count* for each bucket. So if it was possible to get *average* and *variance* of `_size` value instead of just *doc_count* for each `field.length` bucket, that would solve it